# Strange behaviour of exec-function in python 3

Tags: python

Why does this code not work?

```
class wrapper(dict):
    pass

script = """
def foo():
    print(10)

foo()
"""
exec(script, wrapper())
```

When I ran it I got this message:

```
File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
exec(script, wrapper())
 File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 3, in foo
KeyError: 'print'
```

If I change last line to

```
exec(script, {})
```

then everything is ok.

I can not understand, why a totally transparent inheritance of dictionary changes script behavior?

Comment: If i execute your original code with the exec(script, wrapper()) I get the correct output.  What version of python are you using?

Comment: I run it in Python 3.4.3

Comment: FWIW, [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) says, "If only `globals` is provided, it must be a dictionary ... If provided, `locals` can be any mapping object."

Comment: When I run it on python 3.4.3 I get `10` printed out then followed immediately by the KeyError

Comment: In Python 3.5.1 it outputs the 10 with no error.

Comment: No error in 3.1.1 either...

Comment: This behavior can be made using the line: `exec(script, wrapper({'__builtins__':{}}))` However, the error is not reproducible in Python 3.7.1 or 3.6.5

Comment: The fact that your test code has ten lines but the output complains about line #29 means that you have not posted the code that causes the issue. That means there's a better than average chance the problem lies in the code you *haven't* posted, since no-one has been able to reproduce the problem with the code given.

Answer (score 0):

Just a conclusion for your issue here - thanks to other users' comments

Use the latest python version will get your code working

E.g. I use latest 3.8.x with PyCharm and got it run ok

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please use python 3.7 ------your code works correctly for me